# GADM country borders

Tags: polygon, gadm

I have the latest gadm36 geopackage from https://gadm.org/download_world.html.  I'm interested in finding the geometries for entire countries for example, one polygon representing the entire US. Looking through the data, I'm seeing so far are provinces, towns, states, etc.

Does GADM define a polygon for the borders of entire countries or is it only the geometries of smaller subsets of each country?

Comment: I think questions about characteristics of open data are best asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm trying to get all the countries of the world, but I see no single thing in the metadata to filter on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level **0** of each country's GADM data should be its boundary:

https://gadm.org/maps/GBR.html

If you use that page to explore SubDivisions, you'll see what the other levels are for the UK, and drill down.

Individual level 0 data (shapefiles, R data, KML) can be downloaded from the country pages:

https://gadm.org/download_country.html

if you don't want to have to get all the subdivisions.

But if you've already got the GeoPackage, somewhere in that there should be a way to get the level 0 boundaries.

Comment: there are (at least for the current [4.1 version](https://gadm.org/download_world.html)) 2 .gpkg. one [with all the smallest geometries](https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/gadm_410-gpkg.zip) and another [with each level as a layer](https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/gadm_410-levels.zip). if you want to get all the countries, you need to get the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the file with all six layers (gadm_410-levels.zip) from https://gadm.org/download_world.html and modify with python to only have country boundaries in the gpkg file:

```
import geopandas

countries = geopandas.read_file("gadm_410-levels.gpkg", layer="ADM_0")
countries.to_file('gadm_lvl0.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer='ADM_0')
```